# How to remove null entries from Jolt converted output

Tags: json, jolt

I have the below JSON input and I am to able to get the desired output, but also seeing **`null`** entries in the slices for the id's not present. How to avoid **`null`** entries as they are getting created due to **`"$": "node.[&1].id"`**, but I am not sure, if I remove the line then how to read the keys **3** and **6** into **`id`**'s field.

**Input JSON**:

```json
{
  "node": {
    "3": [
      {
        "name": "name3"
      },
      {
        "shutdown": false
      }
    ],
    "6": [
      {
        "name": "name6"
      },
      {
        "shutdown": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Jolt Spec**:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "node": {
        "*": {
          "$": "node.[&1].id",
          "*": {
            "name": "node.[&2].name",
            "shutdown": "node.[&2].shutdown"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Output JSON**:

```json
{
  "node" : [ null, null, null, {
    "id" : "3",
    "name" : "name3",
    "shutdown" : false
  }, null, null, {
    "id" : "6",
    "name" : "name6",
    "shutdown" : false
  } ]
}
```

**Expected output JSON**:

```json
{
  "node" : [ 
 {
    "id" : "3",
    "name" : "name3",
    "shutdown" : false
  }, 
  {
    "id" : "6",
    "name" : "name6",
    "shutdown" : false
  } ]
}
```

If someone can help me what I am missing in above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rather use **`#`** wildcard ( as **`[# ]`** ) along with one incremented integer values(eg. *start counting indexes from **0** unlike to **`[& ]`** on the right-hand-side(RHS) in which we start counting from **1*** ) per each expression  such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "node": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&2[#2].id",
          "*": {
            "name": "&3[#3].name",
            "shutdown": "&3[#3].shutdown"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where

- no need to repeat the literal **`node`** which might already be
  copied by using **`&`** wildcards with different level degrees( `2`,
  `3` )
- adjacent key names( **`&2`** and **`&3`** in this case ) just before **`[# ]`** or **`[& ]`** on the RHS
  don't need an extra period(**`.`**) among them

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros for the response. Can you explain how does the looping happens with & and # being used. I tried to play around but couldn't get much.

Comment: @Lakhan Just count the number of `}` as traversing up the tree for `&` prefixes, count the number of `}` besides `:` as traversing up the tree for `#` prefixes whenever they are stated on the rght-hand-site eg. count starting from `1` for `&`, `0` for `#`( `[&1]` is identical to `[#2]` as an example ).

Comment: Your above solution is working and I am looking on how to Vote the answer. Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you help for one more issue.
`
      {
        "timeout": 55
      }
`
Jolt:
`
{
            "timeout": "&3[#3].no.timeout.\\$\\[<1-7290>\\].\\[<1-7290>\\]"
 }
`
Expected Output:
`
"no" : {
      "timeout" : {
        "$[<1-7290>]" : {
          "[<1-7290>]" : 55
        }
      }
    }
`

But I need the output in the below format with "[" bracket around "$<1-7290>":
`
....
    "no" : {
      "timeout" : {
        "$[<1-7290>]" : {
          "[<1-7290>]" : 55 <<< Not getting "]" in the end after ""[<1-7290>".  "\\[" error

        }
      }
    }
....
`

Comment: I think,it would be better to ask a new question which contains the input, current used spec and expected output,all thoe are cleanly formated, thanks @Lakhan

Comment: Will ask as new Question